# Make window Pop on homepage load

Tags: popup, popupwindow

I want to make a window popup on page load of the homepage

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Copy the following code INTO your BODY tag.

```
< body OnLoad="window.open('http://www.onemanga.com', 'One Manga', 'scrollbars=1, resizable=1');">
```